# "Item not found" when trying to use remote support on Anrdoid

Tags: teamviewer

How can I help my brother with his Android phone. I am in the USA. He is in Cape Town, South Africa on a Huawei P9 lite. He was able to download and install Teamviewer Quicksupport from the [Android Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market&hl=en) . I was able to see specifications about his phone. Alas when I tried to start "remote control" it prompted him to download an add-in[image: add-on available] which it could not find. [image: item not found]

On my side I am using Teamviewer 11.0.63017 License:Free

Answer (score 0):

Some time back, They (for some reason) had to change the link for TeamViewer. It is now [here (Google play)](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details%3Fid%3Dcom.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile%26hl%3Den_GB%26referrer%3Dutm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dorganic%2526utm_term%253Dteamviewer%26pcampaignid%3DAPPU_14_rmqmV9CyEuicgAaswbTgBg&ved=0ahUKEwjQwciK8a3OAhVoDsAKHawgDWwQ5YQBCBswAA&usg=AFQjCNETm_jQih1eqPusjeOcym5xLoypPQ). Once downloaded, you can use it in quick support or stand-alone, depending on your needs. If this fails, it may be down to a region issue- in which case, install an APK instead.

Comment: Hold on! The link you provided is for "TeamViewer for Remote Control" which is what one uses to control a Windows computer from an Android smpartphone. I am wanting to do the opposite. That is why my brother had to download from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market&hl=en and it was that program that worked perfectly until I wanted to take control of his phone and then it invited my brother to download the add on.

Comment: @Farrel Ah, yes, but it still works fine connecting to phones. Look in the settings tab, there will be a team viewer Id. Put that I'd into another phone, you can control it! I sometimes use when I'm out and about to set reminders for when I get home.